# How to create twitter bootstrap CRUD with servlets/jsp

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, servlets

How do I create CRUD with twitter bootstrap (for frontend inside a jsp file) and servlets/jsp.
I have not found a good example to guide me.

1. I want to use twitter bootstrap for frontend - I have a jsp for this.
2. list was for showing content that will be displayed in frontend.

The below is a snippet of the level I have reached.

```
connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
if (request.getParameter("action") != null) {

    List<Content> listContent = new ArrayList<Content>();
    String action = (String) request.getParameter("action");
    Content content = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    if (action.equals("list")) {
        try {
            // Fetch Data from Content Table
            listContent = contentService.getAllContent(connection);
            // Convert Java Object to Json
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(listContent,
                    new TypeToken<List<Content>>() {
                    }.getType());
            JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
            String listData = jsonArray.toString();

            listData = "{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + listData
                + "}";
            response.getWriter().print(listData);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String error = "{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"
                + ex.getMessage() + "}";
            response.getWriter().print(error);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (action.equals("create") || action.equals("update")) {
        content = new Content();
        if (request.getParameter("id") != null) {
            int idField = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            content.setId(idField);
        }
        if (request.getParameter("content") != null) {
            String contentField = (String) request
                .getParameter("content");
            content.setContent(contentField);
        }
        if (request.getParameter("category") != null) {
            String categoryField = (String) request
                .getParameter("category");
            content.setCategory(categoryField);
        }
```

Comment: 1) What twitter-bootstrap has to do with Java and CRUD part? 2) What "list" command has to do with CRUD? Divide the problem and define the question more specifically.

Comment: hi Serhiy, hope now you understand what am trying to come up with.Feel free to ask for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general but I think you want a basic Create Read Update or Delete example,this logic can be done by a Servlet.The twitter bootstrap is majorly used on the front End User Interface design.see similar Spring examples of including twitter BootStrap.

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-with-spring-mvc [Example](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-with-spring-mvc)